# What is "Setup" process on activity monitor?

Tags: macos

This process is taking all my bandwidth, but no idea what it's for?
[image: process capture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the path to the process which will tell you more about what it is.

1. From the gear menu, choose Sample Process.

   [image]
2. Observe the path to the process.

   [image]

   In this example, I sampled Activity Monitor itself, which shows that the Activity Monitor process is inside Activity Monitor.app.

Comment: Great! 
Path:            /Library/Application Support/Adobe/Adobe Desktop Common/HDBox/Setup