# Problem connecting iPhone to iTunes after upgrade to High Sierra

Tags: iphone, itunes, high-sierra, software-update, crash

A week ago, my mac pro 2012 was running Yosemite.  At that point I made a backup of my phone, a 6s. currently running iOS 15.7.6

I then upgraded my mac it to High Sierra.

The night before, my phone updated to 15.7.6 from 15.7.5

Now, when I plug my phone in, this comes up:

[image: update required]

If I click Install I get this about 2 seconds later.

[image]

Repeating this on my wife's High Sierra machine, it downloads installs the patch, and her mac can link to my phone.

I can reproduce this problem with what should become my new phone a iPhone 11 Pro max running 16.5.1

---

From my reading the problem is a program called MobileDeviceUpdater

Console log, filtered for above

```
default 19:41:49.933933 -0600   MobileDeviceUpdater Got an error during the update?! Error Domain=SUSoftwareUpdateErrorDomain Code=106 "Can’t download the software because of a network problem."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Can’t download the software because of a network problem., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f7fd5959a20 {Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)"
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Make sure you’re connected to the Internet, and then try again., SUErrorRelatedCode=SUErrorCodeScanCatalogNotFound}}}
```

I have a 48K crash log that makes no sense to me.

I have put a copy here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16gAFXDf_qBi7uUR3puu9ZM6xojTRWW8S/view?usp=sharing

Anyone who has the link can view.

I'm going to try a reinstall of High Sierra.

**Edit in answer to comments:**

***Dan***
*mac connection to internet*

- Ethernet cable to router.
- Router through power injector to Fixed link LTE radio tranceiver mounted on a 60 foot mast.  Relay to Telfordville tower, relay to Ponoka tower through several more towers.  Fiber Optic to Alberta Supernet.  VPN to ISP headquarters in Fredericton, New Brunswick.

***Ptit Xav***
*Connection to apple*

General connection to Apple is fine.  I can download 300 MB install files in a few minutes.

I don't *think* there is a firewall issue, as I have no problem doing this from another computer running High Sierra.  I am currently using wifi instead of cable, as it's an easy way to change IP addresses.  Same behaviour.

Programs like Transmission torrent downloader works fine.

Comment: Can you go in Apple website from the Mac ? Have you configured a firewall ?

Comment: Don't reinstall High Sierra. This is a waste of time. Here is the useful error message: "Can’t download the software because of a network problem.". Check your network accessibility.

Comment: Could you describe how your Mac pro is connected to the Internet?

Comment: Someone only the other day had an issue relating to this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461301/mac-os-10-13-6-and-newer-mobile-devices-not-working-with-itunes-12-8-3-1-mobiled based on an older QA -  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327310/a-software-update-is-required-to-connect-to-your-ios-device-iphone

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found here: [Mac OS 10.13.6 and newer mobile devices not working with iTunes 12.8.3.1 MobileDeviceUpdater.app not working](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/461301/17533)

In short, you need to download Xcode.app from Apple (which may require registration of a developer account first), then find the MobileDevice.pkg file inside and open it, which should install the missing components.